# comparing characters to tabulation in words of a list

Tags: python-3.x

How can i compare a character with the tab \t  ?

```
lines = trente_words
list_of_words = lines.splitlines()
print(list_of_words)

for word in list_of_words:
    if word[0] != '\\t'
    word[0] = word[1]
```

This, and \t, '\t',  do not work, SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 41)
Every line in my file is written with an English word followed by a Vietnamese word like
Word    từ    : 999th line
my goal is to remove each English word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors.  A valid version might be:

```py
for word in list_of_words:
    if word[0] != '\t':     # '\t' is a literal tab character
        word[0] = word[1]
```

But I sense that maybe you want to strip leading tabs or whitespace from each line.  If so, then we can use `re.sub` for that:

```
for word in list_of_words:
    word = re.sub(r'^\s+', '', word)
    # do something with the word
```

Comment: Thank you, the errors came from the missed " : " at the end of the line if !  but now i have an other error at following line. It looks like " word[0] = word[1] "  is not allowed for strings  :  " TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment "   my goal is not to remove spaces or tab, i want to remove all letters before tabulation in each line (English words)  :-)